# how to connect vodafone k3800 dongle in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: networking

I have tried to connect vodafone k3800 dongle but it cannot be connected even when dongle Indicating green light ( It means GRRS is connected )..
Help Please!!
I am New to ubuntu

Comment: i have same problem please let me know your Ubuntu favour 32bit or 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

1. The K3800 dongle have internal read only memory, which contains driver files for linux. Copy the driver file to your local storage
2. Extract the compressed file
3. Go to command terminal
4. Navigate to the directory in which the extracted driver files dumped in.
5. Use the command `sudo ./install.sh`

Comment: Hello just installed vodafone dongal driver but application is not launching when i click on vodafone k3800 in application curser is just loading but application is not launching..

Comment: You need to unplug the device and insert it again to get it worked... :)